# Cocoa. Is there a way to completely disable autolayout/constraints for all windows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm building a programmatically generated UI using Cocoa and having autolayout/constraints automatically generated for each view kills all the markup i'm trying to achieve. Is there a way to completely disable autolayout? I would rather use good old setFrame manually, i don't need any resizing or anything fancy. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for your views.

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

> If this property’s value is YES, the system creates a set of
>   constraints that duplicate the behavior specified by the view’s
>   autoresizing mask.
>
> By default, the property is set to YES for any view you
>   programmatically create. If you add views in Interface Builder, the
>   system automatically sets this property to NO.

Comment: have you tried that? i had that off already andi can still see bunch of constraints generated in debugger and it ignores frames i'm setting cause there's a fixed size in one of constraints

Comment: Yes, it works. I assume this property must be set before adding the view to a superview.

Comment: Is it only your own views, or do you use third party components?

Comment: its my views (NSStackView and NSButton for now) and i'm creating them from code. i set the flag immediately after i create an object. most of the google answers are about view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints or overloading requiresConstraintBasedLayout but none worked for me so far

Comment: I think the `NSStackView` is your problem. According to docs It uses auto-layout, so I don't think you can use them unless you use constraints.
Check the Overview section: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstackview

Comment: i definitely missed that part, thanks! but still, even if i remove NSStackView and replace it with NSView and then add a button like this `NSButton* heading = [NSButton buttonWithTitle:text target:nil action:nil];
  heading.bezelStyle = NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle;
  heading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [heading setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(200, heading.frame.size.height)];` it has constraints and ignores frame size. i must be missing something else, something really simple

Comment: basically i can move & resize NSView alright, but not the NSButton for some reason. it has width/height constraints

Comment: Could you check what result you get from `requiresConstraintBasedLayout` on your parent view? And also `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on your parent view.

Comment: `unsigned int styleMask = NSWindowStyleMaskTitled;
  NSPanel* panel = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200) styleMask:styleMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
  BOOL needsL = [[panel.contentView class] requiresConstraintBasedLayout];` says NO. it looks like [panel setContentView:view] resets the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES but even if i force it to NO nothing changes

Comment: Hmm, you must have some other problem. I just tested to create a MacOS Cocoa app from Xcode. I created a single `NSButton`, set its frame, and added it to `self.window.contentView`. It appears fine with my size and position.

Comment: could be related to my setup, yeah. basically i have a parent nswindow, then i create a child NSPanel, set a custom NSView as a contentView, then create another nested NSView which has NSButton and NSView. i can control sizes of all nsviews fine now but not the NSButton. anyways, thanks for help! will keep digging

Comment: i guess that's the reason https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW21 which leaves us with question why yours sample worked